# Scroll bar on modal is not working in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css

I have a modal with scrollbar and its not working in firefox and IE and working ok in chrome and opera browser

[**fiddle**][1]

```
     [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/nb9g2hj2/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `max-height: 60%;`  but 60% from what exacly you should define a **height** to the **parent** of just use **fixed height** to it like this

```css
.modelheight1 {
 overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-----Terms and Condition Modal----->
                
                <div class="modal fade" id="termsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>-->
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Terms and Conditions</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modelheight1" id="modalBody1">
        <p style="text-align:justify;" id="modalTerms">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum non ipsum at magna finibus rhoncus a vitae leo. Phasellus id nibh luctus, gravida elit pellentesque, consectetur sem. Nulla fringilla, nulla et egestas rhoncus, sem risus iaculis neque, eget aliquam mauris erat vitae nulla. Vivamus placerat est lectus, ac molestie orci tincidunt a. Aliquam ac viverra sapien, sed vestibulum ex. Fusce malesuada ut arcu at porttitor. Cras suscipit leo vel varius venenatis. Nullam aliquam non elit a lacinia.

Morbi vulputate, purus in dictum luctus, urna sapien auctor neque, at venenatis turpis justo nec neque. Etiam a tortor turpis. Quisque auctor nec neque sed viverra. Maecenas sit amet nisl risus. Aenean ut felis eu diam vehicula porttitor. Donec eget nunc est. Nunc porttitor felis sem, eu tristique erat auctor et. Donec sed magna nunc. Nulla pretium orci quis sem dictum volutpat.

Morbi vulputate, purus in dictum luctus, urna sapien auctor neque, at venenatis turpis justo nec neque. Etiam a tortor turpis. Quisque auctor nec neque sed viverra. Maecenas sit amet nisl risus. Aenean ut felis eu diam vehicula porttitor. Donec eget nunc est. Nunc porttitor felis sem, eu tristique erat auctor et. Donec sed magna nunc. Nulla pretium orci quis sem dictum volutpat.

Morbi vulputate, purus in dictum luctus, urna sapien auctor neque, at venenatis turpis justo nec neque. Etiam a tortor turpis. Quisque auctor nec neque sed viverra. Maecenas sit amet nisl risus. Aenean ut felis eu diam vehicula porttitor. Donec eget nunc est. Nunc porttitor felis sem, eu tristique erat auctor et. Donec sed magna nunc. Nulla pretium orci quis sem dictum volutpat.
</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" disabled aria-hidden="true" id="agreeBtn">Agree</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
                <!-----End T&C Modal----->
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nb9g2hj2/1/